# Tabindex and overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. I have an Instagram feed by Instagrams API, which pulls image, likes, comments and description. The description under the image is shorted by this css:

```
#instagram-feed .meta-data p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: #000;
}
```

I have also added a script which creates links on hashtags, so you can click them directly in the feed.

This works great. Until you are starting to tab the page. Since the text/hashtags is hidden after one row, it is still in the HTML-structure, just not visible.

So what happends when I am tab the the page and get to the Instagram feed is that the tabindex finds the hidden hashtags. But they are invisible. Only the focus frame shows around the hidden hashtags.

`tabindex="-1"` removes element from tabindex which I want to add to overflowing/hidden links, but I can't do this manually since the description is dynamically created. I need better CSS (If possible) or somekind of jQuery. But I have no idea how.

So my question is, how do I remove hidden links from tabindex? :)

Edit:

Trying this to see what elements is inside or outside the parent:

http://jsfiddle.net/fprm7mgd/8/. The link inside the third paragraph should be red.

On the site the `position().left;` in the third `p` is something like 670px, when running console.log. But in reality the a is about 130px right from its parent left side. It seems like `position().left;` goes from parent div, not from parent p...

[image: Instagram feed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add... `position:relative` ... to the paragraphs.

`position().left` use its offset element, which in this case is `<html>`. In other words, `position().left` works exactly as `position: absolute` in CSS. If the parent is not `position: relative` it counts from the `<html>`-element.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/fprm7mgd/47/

Comment: you are a life saviour .